# How to export a global variables/arrays from the dll built using VS compiler to the client built using MingW compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mingw, compatibility, dllimport

**General info [optional]:**
I have recently acquantied with static & dynamic libraries.
Now I am trying to learn how to use DLLs, I try to immitate all possible variants of usage in order to encounter possible bottlenecks and methods to prevent them.

**My goal:**
Is to find out **how to export a global variable from a DLL which was compiled with one compiler for ex. VS compiler (IDE Visual studio 2010) to the client which was compiled using another compiler MingW(IDE Qt Creator 5.0).** Actually I am interested in specific case, not common, but if info for common case will be provided - it will be great.
Also **important that connection of the dll to the client is implicit**(not expilcit then we manually connect library).
Also I have posed such question because it is interesting for me **how to support a client`s application by providing updated dll**, because version of compiler used for client and dll at the beggining of a project can be the same, but as time passes by they may vary, so how to solve this binary compatibility issue?
**I got stuck trying to export an array defined in dll to the client.**
  DLL & Client

```
        /* header file. Is used by both: dll and client */
#ifdef EXPORT
    #define MYLIB __declspec(dllexport)
#else 
    #define MYLIB __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


extern "C" { // My be this directive not supported by MingW???

#ifdef VS2010 
    extern MYLIB char ImplicitDLLName[];
#else
    Q_DECL_IMPORT extern char ImplicitDLLName[];
#endif
}
```

DLL

```
/* .cpp file in dll: */
#define EXPORT ""
#define VS2010 ""
char ImplicitDLLName[] = "MySUMoperator";
```

Client
/* Client .cpp */

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonAdd_clicked()
{
    // ...
    printf("%s",ImplicitDLLName);

}
```

Attempt to use the array in the Client results in the following error raised by the linker:

```
 error: undefined reference to `_imp__ImplicitDLLName'
```

I am aware of names mangling and compatibilty issue that may arise from that, but I am trying to resolve it by disabeling it using

```
extern "C"{}
```

By the error returned from the client`s linker I can tell that I have failed to disable it, because it reports that reference on _imp__ImplicitDLLName wasn`t found, so I guess that it is ImplicitDLLName only decorated with additional symobls(name mangling).
I wonder may be this issue arose due to different implementation of arrays in different compilers or  alignment of arrays in memory??
**Question: how to solve this binary comptability issue??**

Comment: Why do you use 'extern MYLIB' in the export, but 'Q_DECL_IMPORT extern' in the import?

Comment: Because DLL is compiled and built in Visual Studio 2010 where is used Microsoft compiler and __declspec(dllexport) is a Microsoft specific for exporting from dll and in Qt I use MingW compiler